FFMPeg: Avoiding clipping of image when rotating overlay
Im trying to add an image overlay on top of a video and have to rotated the image arbitrarily.
Below is the command I'm using to rotate by -30 deg.
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4  -i crown.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba, rotate=-30*PI/180:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=80:10" -codec:a copy sample.mp4

I've left out c=none to better vizualize the overlay for now.
Below is how the rotated image looks:

As seen above, when rotating the top part gets clipped presumably because of the width of the overlay - which I'm not able to figure out how to reliably change. Depending on the dimension of image, width, height or both gets clipped. What is the right approach here to avoid this?

wrong rotw roth param: rotate=-30*PI/180:ow='rotw(-30*PI/180)':oh='roth(-30*PI/180)'

Oh, Thank you..! This works..
